# Win32 - Get Main Wnd Handle of application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have injected my dll into process.
How can I get Main window handle of host application?

Comment: I think "victim application" is a better term than "host application".  If gunmen stormed into my house and held me hostage, I'd be the victim, not the host.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The host application may have multiple 'main windows'. To detect them, you could

1. Call [`GetCurrentProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the PID of the current process
2. Call [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) to iterate over all toplevel windows of the desktop
3. For each window on the desktop, call [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the PID of the process which created the window
4. If the PID of the window matches the PID of your own process, memorize the window.

That gives you a list of toplevel windows created by the process which you injected your DLL into. However, please note that this approach may yield windows which have been destroyed by the time you process the constructed list of windows. Hence, when doing something with the windows, make sure to use the [`IsWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528(v=vs.85).aspx) function to ensure that the window at hand is still valid (this is still prone to race conditions since the window may become invalid between your call to `IsWindow` and actually accessing the window, but the time window is much smaller).

Here's a C++ function implementing this algorithm. It implements a `getToplevelWindows` function which yields a `std::vector<HWND>` containing the handles of all toplevel windows of the current process.

```
struct EnumWindowsCallbackArgs {
    EnumWindowsCallbackArgs( DWORD p ) : pid( p ) { }
    const DWORD pid;
    std::vector<HWND> handles;
};

static BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsCallback( HWND hnd, LPARAM lParam )
{
    EnumWindowsCallbackArgs *args = (EnumWindowsCallbackArgs *)lParam;

    DWORD windowPID;
    (void)::GetWindowThreadProcessId( hnd, &windowPID );
    if ( windowPID == args->pid ) {
        args->handles.push_back( hnd );
    }

    return TRUE;
}

std::vector<HWND> getToplevelWindows()
{
    EnumWindowsCallbackArgs args( ::GetCurrentProcessId() );
    if ( ::EnumWindows( &EnumWindowsCallback, (LPARAM) &args ) == FALSE ) {
      // XXX Log error here
      return std::vector<HWND>();
    }
    return args.handles;
}
```

**UPDATE:** These days (about four years after I gave the answer) I would also consider [traversing the list of threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms686852(v=vs.85).aspx) of the application and then using [`EnumThreadWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms633495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on each thread. I noticed that this is considerably faster in many cases.

Comment: I got curious about the performance between `EnumWindows` and `EnumThreadWindows`; In my tests, `EnumWindows` is much faster: 4ms vs 200ms when using `EnumThreadWindows`. I posted my implementation here only for reference: https://gist.github.com/gaspardpetit/3b1a10f6a2a9866b2bba8eb5d8e4ef36

Answer (score 1):

Small addition to the previous answer - main application window have no parent, so GetParent() will return zero for it.