# Getting the last active window's title of a process running under system account in services

Tags: visual-c++, cmd, window, title

We need to get the  last active window's title of a process.

Currently We are using the command `tasklist /v` and parsing it to get the window title.

**Problem:**

We are not able to get the last active window's title if we run the command under `system account in services`.

**Output If we run under windows account/system account (not from services):**

<kbd>Image Name</kbd>
<kbd>PID</kbd> 
<kbd>Session Name</kbd>
<kbd>Session#</kbd>
<kbd>Mem Usage</kbd>
<kbd>Status</kbd>  
<kbd>User Name</kbd>
<kbd>CPU Time</kbd>
<kbd>Window Title</kbd>                                  

<kbd>firefox.exe</kbd>   
<kbd>4476</kbd>
<kbd>Console</kbd>         
<kbd>1</kbd>            
<kbd>509,224 K</kbd>   
<kbd>Running</kbd>
<kbd>Ramesh</kbd>    
<kbd>0:01:47</kbd>    
<kbd>Getting the window title of a process</kbd>

**Output If we run under windows account/system account (from services):**

<kbd>Image Name</kbd>
<kbd>PID</kbd> 
<kbd>Session Name</kbd>
<kbd>Session#</kbd>
<kbd>Mem Usage</kbd>
<kbd>Status</kbd>  
<kbd>User Name</kbd>
<kbd>CPU Time</kbd>
<kbd>Window Title</kbd>

<kbd>firefox.exe</kbd>   
<kbd>4476</kbd>
<kbd>Console</kbd>         
<kbd>1</kbd>            
<kbd>509,224 K</kbd>   
<kbd>Running</kbd>
<kbd>Ramesh</kbd>    
<kbd>0:01:47</kbd>    
<kbd>N/A</kbd>

Our application is running under system account from services. Is there a way to get the windows title from a program running under system account from services?

Comment: Can anyone suggest improvements or corrections to this?

Comment: It's not even clear what "*the* window title" is: A process can have many windows with different titles. I don't think you'd be able to do anything useful without some code to dig out the top-level windows and somehow decide which is the one you're referring to as "the" window.   Here's one pointer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202547/win32-get-main-wnd-handle-of-application

Comment: @OfekShilon If you run the command 'tasklist /v' in the command prompt, you will get a column called window title which will have the `last active window of a process multiple windows`. That's what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Vista and later Windows service run in a separate session. When a user logs in a Terminal Services enabled computer a new session is created with each logon. That's the reason we are not able to access the window title of a process since it is running under different session.

However, an interactive service can display a user interface and receive user input. To access the window title of the process in another user's session, I need to create an interactive services.

MSDN article: [Interactive services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).